# Query on component templates

Tags: angular, redux, angular2-services, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Suppose I have a component
**ListOptionsMenu**, this component receives through its input the list of options of 1 menu.

Now suppose that in a view have 4 menus, then I use **ListOptionsMenu** template but before I create another **ListFatherOptionsMenu** component to control the logic of the data.

In **ListFatherOptionsMenu**, I have in its constructor a **menuService**, this in its ngOnInit, calls to the method of the service that is in charge to bring the data of option of the menu according to the type **this.menuService.getOptions (type);**
Then the parent component passes to the child the options that it picked up from the service, and there is no problem in that, every 1 of the 4 menus has its corresponding options.

Now suppose I want to dynamically change the menu options, I click on a menu option that allows me to log in, the login panel opens and the 4 menus are still in the same view, just change the body, I log in and here comes the Problem, once I log in successfully, I want to change the list of options of 2 menus with a new call to the api, 1 to update the menu from login-register to logout (I know is simple), and another to update the Main menu when the user enters.

Then in **ListFatherOptionsMenu** could use the **communication between services** to link it with some observable, or use redux with **ngrx / store** and **ngrx / effects**, the problem here is that this component does not know to whom to send the data collected from the observable, and if it is sent this Is replicated in the 4 child components.

I then decided to remove this parent component and control the logic of the data from the same child components.

But the problem here is the same, if I connect an observable to a service (the one of login) to change the data (call to an api through a service), or using redux (a store), this being in the constructor, Is the same for all **ListOptionsMenu**, then at any change the 4 components are affected.

I thought that maybe adding a switch to the constructor and loading the appropriate store / observable according to the type of menu, could solve this problem, so when the user logs on, menuA, storeA is loaded, B store B and Other that do not change is not loaded any store, however I do not think a very clean option to say.

I need help to see how to control the flow of information in this type of cases, since it not only extends to many options but to any type of components that are needed as templates for other services.

Any kind of help, thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to load different menu options depending on the user that is logged in?

Comment: Seems to be not the problem of components communication (parent -> child or redux bindings, doesn't matter at all), but the components architecture approach is not fully clean..
If you have 4 instances of 1 component (your ListOptionsMenu for example), you just need to provide DIFFERENT properties on theirs inputs.. simply clever and no over way round.
if you dependent on 1 API call - so just create 1 method to init your service call and 4 observables from it to subscribe (or manage it in parent component)
or just dispatch 1 action for ngrx and write 4 reducers who listen to this..

Comment: For srAxi, for this almost if, but this can be extended to more use cases, for example in a menuList (leave aside the menu of options), this menuList is already for Post, Users, etc, etc, connected to a Socket, so this menu will be dynamically loaded with the socket data in the corresponding channel.

Comment: For Oleg Banirov, I think your point, being ListOptionsMenu, a silly component, should in the ListFatherOptionsMenu parent control the behavior of the information that I will pass to my 4 silly components, in this parent component, I must make the switch between the 4 different Stores to be able to pass the corresponding options, such as the authentication component where the register-login options are displayed, and changes when logging is logged.

Comment: The behavior of these would be in a reductor, and the same for the other cases, I see feasible, however to avoid doing repost as I would have to explain the context, how could dynamically load a stile.css for this child component? And erase or remove the others.